# Matrices in ConTeXt?

Tags: math-mode, context

I'm typesetting up some linear algebra notes, and in the process moving from LaTeX to ConTeXt.  What is the most efficient method of entering matrices in ConTeXt?  I can use plain TeX:

```
\startformula
\left[matrix{
1&2&3\cr
4&5&-6\cr}
\right]
\stopformula
```

which is OK, but typesets all elements centered in their columns.  To obtain right-aligned elements I'd have to add lots of `hfill`'s through the matrix.

Alternatively:

```
\startformula
\startmmatrix[align={right,right,right}]
\NC 1 \NC 2 \NC 3 NR
\NC 5 \NC 6 \NC -6 \NR
\stopmmatrix
\stopformula
```

which works, but is very wordy and cumbersome (I much prefer the "&, \" of LaTeX here).  What is the canonical way of obtaining right-aligned entries in ConTeXt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The canonical way is to use `\definemathmatrix`.

```
\definemathmatrix[rightmatrix]
                 [left={\left[\,},
                  right={\,\right]},
                  align=right]

\startformula
\startrightmatrix
   \NC ... \NC ... \NR
   \NC ... \NC ... \NR
\stoprightmatrix
\stopformula
```

In some ways, the ConTeXt style encourages you to separate content from presentation.

Typing `\NC` ... `\NR` can be simplified a bit by using editor macros. But that is not all that verbose compared to `&` and `\\`.

Also see Section 3 of this [MAPS article](http://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/context-latex-math.pdf) that compares LaTeX and ConTeXt matrices.

Comment: Only the first column is right aligned when I try this. Has the meaning of `align=right` changed since this answer?